ImportError: cannot import name 'mmr_auxe' from partially initialized module 'niftypet.nipet'
I have installed niftypet into my desktop but when I am trying to run in in python i.e when I am trying to import it I am getting the following error (Nipet is a package in niftypet):
from niftypet import nipet

Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[12], line 1
    from niftypet import nipet

  File ~\NIPET\niftypet\nipet\__init__.py:45
    from . import img, lm, mmraux, mmrnorm, prj

  File ~\NIPET\niftypet\nipet\prj\__init__.py:3
    from . import mmrprj, mmrrec, mmrsim

  File ~\NIPET\niftypet\nipet\prj\mmrrec.py:20
    from ..sct import vsm

  File ~\NIPET\niftypet\nipet\sct\__init__.py:3
    from . import mmrsct

  File ~\NIPET\niftypet\nipet\sct\mmrsct.py:16
    from .. import mmr_auxe, mmraux, mmrnorm

ImportError: cannot import name 'mmr_auxe' from partially initialized module 'niftypet.nipet' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\Dell\NIPET\niftypet\nipet\__init__.py)


Please help me. Any help will be appreciated. I am working on a windows system.
I was expecting it to import nipet with the line from niftypet import nipet, but unfortunately its throwing an error.
I tried importing it inside a function to remove circular error but it's still throwing the same error.

instead doing from niftypet import nipet, do some thing like from niftypet.nipet import  classnameorlibraryname for each nipet use, import each time with specific file.
